# Can Eclipse indent new line with 1 tab after JavaScript array initializer?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, indentation

I'm using Eclipse to edit JavaScript files and I guess I'm "doing it wrong". Given the following code, where 
`»` represents a tab,
`·` represents a space, and 
`|` represents the cursor:

```
function·foo()·{
»   var·baz·=·[|
}
```

If I hit enter at this point, I get

```
function·foo()·{
»   var·baz·=·[
»   ···········|
}
```

Yuck. I would much rather get

```
function·foo()·{
»   var·baz·=·[
»   »   |
}
```

I've dug through the various "Typing" and "Formatter" preferences to no success. Did I overlook something? Or is there a particular incantation that I must chant or spell I can cast on Eclipse, to make it behave this way? Thanks.

Comment: Just bumped into this, did you find a solution? I guess this can be avoided/configured using some other editor (Aptana, for example), but did you find a way to do it with stock Eclipse?

Comment: Nope... I think the problem lies in Eclipse inheriting the implementation for JavaScript formatting from the implementation of Java formatting... but in an incomplete way.

Comment: Ok, I didn't find solution myself. I guess it would be good to raise a ticket in Eclipse bug tracker about this. I'll probably add one when I have extra time.

Comment: almostly 3 years after and yet no fix for such problem...

Answer (score 3):

Indeed a (bug|weird feature|annoyance) of the Eclipse Javascript editor.

The quickest <strike>hack</strike> way I found to overcome this is to quickly insert an empty js object and hit the Format shortcut and let the Eclipse javascript editor to sort out the tabs:

```
function·foo()·{var·baz·=·[{}]}
```

hit format:

```
function·foo()·{
»   var·baz·=·[
»   »   {}
»   ]
}
```

This also works for an empty string with double / single quotes instead of an empty object.

Note: The Aptana v2 js editor works fine.